# How to send notification from admin to user in Django

Tags: django, push-notification

I am building an online shopping website using Django framework. I want to implement an order approval system where Django Admin will approve the order request from the user and at that time a notification or message will be sent to the user.

Currently I have an order request model with an order status field. When the value of that field will be set approved by the admin a notification will be sent to that user.

I want a push notification system here. How can I implement this in Django?